# How to create Feign Oauth2RequestIntercetor using WebClient with Spring Security 5.2.x?

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-cloud-feign

I am using Feign client in my application with Spring Security 5.2 which is required swapping API bindings from `RestTemplate` to the `WebClient`. I configured my web client to use web client with `OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager` to manage access token provided by `client_credentials` flow. And now I want to create Feign's `RequestInterceptor` for my Feign client which will use this `WebClient`. How do I do this?

Here's my `WebClientConfiguration`:

```
@Configuration
public class WebClientConfig {
    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
            ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
            OAuth2AuthorizedClientService clientService) {

        OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =
                OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                        .refreshToken()
                        .clientCredentials()
                        .build();

        AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager =
                new AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                        clientRegistrationRepository, clientService);
        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);

        return authorizedClientManager;
    }

    @Bean
    WebClient azureGraphAPIWebClient(OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager) {
        ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth2Client =
                new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
        oauth2Client.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("registration-id");
        return WebClient.builder()
                .apply(oauth2Client.oauth2Configuration())
                .build();
    }
}
```